# Table of displayed formulae

Tags: arrays, math-table

I'm trying to make a table of formulae. I've tried a bunch of different approaches (including `\parbox`, `align`, `eqnarray`, etc.), but none of these satisfy all of the requirements:

- `\hline` (or something equivalent) can still be used.
- Vertical lines can be put between columns
- Every cell can contain a formula in `\displaystyle`
- Formulae are centered both horizontally and vertically.

Does anybody know an environment that does this?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @adn: didn't have one; only examples that meet part of the criteria

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the `array` packages offers a partial solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{8pt}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}c|>{\displaystyle}c>{\displaystyle}c|>{\displaystyle}c}
\frac{x}{y}&z&\frac{x}{y}&\frac{x}{y}\\[1em]\hline
\frac{x}{y}&\frac{x}{y}&z&\frac{x}{y}\\[1em]\hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `>{\displaystyle}c` argument appears to produce errors when used in a beamer frame...

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle} c <{$}}
\begin{document} 

\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin {tabular}{| C | C |}\hline
\frac1{1+x^2} & \mathrm{atan}(x)+C \\\hline
\sqrt{x^2+h}  & \ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+h}\right)+C\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of table, it's also possible to use the next code. I keep `\tvi`to get the same height for each row and I use `p{#1}` to control the width of each column.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}      
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tvi}{\vrule height 17pt depth15pt width 0pt} 

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\hfil$\displaystyle} p{#1} <{$\hfil}} 

\begin{tabular}{x{4cm} x{4cm} }\\
\text{\bfseries{Fonctions}}   & \text{\bfseries{ Primitives}}       \\ \midrule
\tvi   \frac{ 1} {1+x^2 }     & \mathrm{ arctan}\,(x)+C             \\ \midrule 
\tvi   \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+h}} & \log\bigl(x+\sqrt{x^2+h}\,\bigr)+C  \\                                                                         
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without an environment but with an old method : `TeX`

```
\def\hfq{\hfill\quad}
\def\cc#1{\hfq#1\hfq}
\def\tvi{\vrule height 12pt depth 5pt width 0pt}
\def\tv{\tvi\vrule}

\vbox{\offinterlineskip
\halign {\tv#&&\cc{$\displaystyle#$}&\tv#\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
&\omit\cc{\bf Fonctions}&&\omit\cc{\bf Primitives}&\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
height 17pt depth15pt&{1\over 1+x^2}&&{\rm Arctg}\,(x)+C&\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
height 17pt depth17pt&{1\over\displaystyle\sqrt{x^2+h}}&&
\log\bigl(x+\sqrt{x^2+h}\,\bigr)+C&\cr
\noalign{\hrule}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, it's debatable whether vertical lines are really necessary in such a table.

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer an alternatively solution. I wouldn't use any lines to box the equations, especially as this is a "Table of Formulae", which should have a similar style to the rest of the tables of contents. It is also likely that the table will go over a page so rather use a `longtable`. It is also a good idea to include the page reference where the equation was firstly described.

You should have the notation or lists of symbols preceding such a table,

[image]

Followed by a pagebreak and the Table of Formulas

[image]

Here is the minimal,

```
\documentclass[crown]{octavo}
\usepackage{longtable,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}[2000/07/18] 
\usepackage{amssymb}[2002/01/22] 
\newcommand{\DittoMark}{``}%''
\newcommand{\Ditto}{\quad\DittoMark\quad}
\newcommand{\Headings}[1]{\textbf{\small#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{General}
\label{aref}%
 \[e= \frac{2}{a}
             \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} \] 

\chapter{TABLE OF FORMULAS.}
\markboth{\Headings{PLANE GEOMETRY.}}{\Headings{TABLE OF FORMULAS.}}%

\subsection{PLANE FIGURES.}

\subsection{NOTATION.}

\begin{tabular}{r@{~}c@{~}l}
$P$ &=& perimeter. \\
$h$ &=& altitude. \\
$b$ &=& lower base. \\
$b'$ &=& upper base. \\
$R$ &=& radius of circle. \\
$D$ &=& diameter of circle. \\
$C$ &=& circumference of circle. \\
$r$ &=& apothem of regular polygon. \\
$a$, $b$, $c$ &=& sides of triangle. \\
$s$ &=& \( \frac{1}{2}(a+b+c) \). \\
$p$ &=& perpendicular of triangle. \\
$m,n$ &=& segments of third side of triangle adjacent to \\
&& sides $b$ and $a$, respectively. \\
$S$ &=& area. \\
$\pi$ &=& 3.1416.
\end{tabular}

\newpage
\subsection{FORMULAS.}

\noindent\begin{longtable}{lr@{~}c@{~}l@{\qquad}r}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\hspace{-2ex}\textbf{Line Values.}} \\
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\tiny PAGE}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Altitude of triangle on side $a$,} \\
& $h$ &=& \( \displaystyle \frac{2}{a}
             \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} \) & \pageref{aref} \\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Median of triangle on side $a$,} \\
& $m$ &=& \( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2(b^2+c^2) - a^2} \) & \pageref{aref} \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\hspace{-2ex}\textbf{Areas.}} \\
Rectangle,     & $S$ &=& $b\times h$ & \pageref{aref} \\
Square,        & $S$ &=& $b^2$ & \pageref{aref} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```