# Displaying table with equations

Tags: tables, tabularx, arrays

How can I display this table with an equation? I tried many times but i can't find any solution to display the table

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{booktabs, collcell, makecell, tabularx, threeparttable, multirow}
        \newcommand{\tclr}[1]{\textcolor{blue!70!black}{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\tclr\raggedright}X<{\endcollectcell}}
       %{\textwidth}{@{} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} @{}}
    
    \usepackage{xparse}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
    
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\mid}{\mid}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
                                L l
                           *{3}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}S}
                                @{}}
    \toprule
    MOP & Definition & Constraints\\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Schaffer Problem}
    & $F=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ & $-10^5\leq x\leq 10^5$ \\
    & $f_1(x)=x^2,$       & \\
    & $f_2(x)=(x-2)^2$    & \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{Viennet (3)}
    & $ F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y))$                          & $-4\leq x,y\leq4 $ \\
    & $ f_1(x,y)=0.5(x^2+y^2)+sin(x^2+y^2),$                     & \\
    & $ f_2(x,y)=\frac{(3x-2y+4)^2}{8}+\frac{(x-y+1)^2}{27}+15,$ & \\
    & $ f_3(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}-1.1 e^{-x^2-y^2}$           & \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Kursawe problem}
    & $ F=(f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}))$                                                           & $-5\leq x_i\leq5$ \\
    & $ f_1(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(-10 \exp\left(-0.2\sqrt{x_i^2+y_{i+1}^2}\right)\right),$ & $i=1,2,3$ \\
    & $ f_2(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\abs{x_i}^{0.8}+5 sin(x_i^3)\right)$                         & \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{Dep problem}
    & $ F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$                                   & $0\leq x,y\leq1$ \\
    & $ f_1(x,y)=x$,                                             & \\
    & $ f_2(x,y)=(1+10y)\Bigl(1-\Bigl(\frac{x}{1+10y}\Bigr)^2- $ & \\
    & $ \qquad \qquad \frac{x}{1+10y}sin(2p\pi x)\Bigr)$         & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Unconstrained Functions}
    \label{unconstrained}
    \end{table}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important things first. When dealing with new things, acquiring new skills, etc. keep things simple, do examples only with strictly necessary information. Everything else is a disturb and makes things susceptible to errors. This is the philosophy behind [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133)s. You gonna read along the answer all methodology I used to find the issue, identify your objetive with this table and only then applying a solution.

That said, the first problem I found was: `Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (S): 'c' used. \end{tabularx}`. You used a column type named `S` which was not defined. You also defined (or let definitions someone else gave you) which were not used. Therefore, next step, change usage of `S` to anything basic, like `l` or `c`. Next, remove also non necessary packages and commands.

At this point we have the first working table with: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l l c @{}}`. Now the rain's gone.

It became clear you use `sin` instead of `\sin`. Checked and corrected. You created a special `\abs` delimiter, as it could be prone to errors, I removed it and let `|x_i|` where it was being used. Reinsert it, if it is necessary on anything else.

Finally I understood your real intention with your `\newcolumntype`. You wanted a column with `\displaystyle`. Following this answer

- [Table of displayed formulae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38259/140133)

I created: `\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle} l <{$}}`. Applying `L`
in the `tabularx` we got an error: `Missing $ inserted. \end{tabularx}`. Basically, we are using `$` twice, so let's remove it (a job for: `Search and Replace`). I chose to create a new table in order to be clear and didactic.

I used at this second table `\textrm{Definition}` and `\text{Constraints}` because they are text, not math. you may choose between both command options. To finish, let's use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}` from:

- [How to set the space between rows in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102996/140133)

to make the table a lit bit more readable.

---

The MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, multirow}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle} l <{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l l c @{}}
    \toprule
    MOP                               & Definition                                                                                     & Constraints            \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Schaffer Problem} & $F=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$                                                                            & $-10^5\leq x\leq 10^5$ \\
                                      & $f_1(x)=x^2$                                                                                   &                        \\
                                      & $f_2(x)=(x-2)^2$                                                                               &                        \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{Viennet (3)}      & $F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y))$                                                               & $-4\leq x,y\leq4 $     \\
                                      & $f_1(x,y)=0.5(x^2+y^2)+\sin(x^2+y^2)$                                                          &                        \\
                                      & $f_2(x,y)=\frac{(3x-2y+4)^2}{8}+\frac{(x-y+1)^2}{27}+15$                                       &                        \\
                                      & $f_3(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}-1.1 e^{-x^2-y^2}$                                                &                        \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Kursawe problem}  & $F=(f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}))$                                                          & $-5\leq x_i\leq5$      \\
                                      & $f_1(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(-10 \exp\left(-0.2\sqrt{x_i^2+y_{i+1}^2}\right)\right)$ & $i=1,2,3$              \\
                                      & $f_2(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(|{x_i}|^{0.8}+5 \sin(x_i^3)\right)$                         &                        \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Dep problem}      & $F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$                                                                        & $0\leq x,y\leq1$       \\
                                      & $f_1(x,y)=x$                                                                                   &                        \\
                                      & $f_2(x,y)=(1+10y)\Bigl(1-\Bigl(\frac{x}{1+10y}\Bigr)^2- \frac{x}{1+10y}\sin(2p\pi x)\Bigr)$    &                        \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L L @{}}
    \toprule
    MOP                               & \textrm{Definition}                                                                          & \text{Constraints}   \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Schaffer Problem} & F=(f_1(x),f_2(x))                                                                            & -10^5\leq x\leq 10^5 \\
                                      & f_1(x)=x^2                                                                                   &                      \\
                                      & f_2(x)=(x-2)^2                                                                               &                      \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{Viennet (3)}      & F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y))                                                               & -4\leq x,y\leq4      \\
                                      & f_1(x,y)=0.5(x^2+y^2)+\sin(x^2+y^2)                                                          &                      \\
                                      & f_2(x,y)=\dfrac{(3x-2y+4)^2}{8}+\frac{(x-y+1)^2}{27}+15                                      &                      \\
                                      & f_3(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}-1.1 e^{-x^2-y^2}                                               &                      \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Kursawe problem}  & F=(f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}))                                                          & -5\leq x_i\leq5      \\
                                      & f_1(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(-10 \exp\left(-0.2\sqrt{x_i^2+y_{i+1}^2}\right)\right) & i=1,2,3              \\
                                      & f_2(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(|{x_i}|^{0.8}+5 \sin(x_i^3)\right)                         &                      \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Dep problem}      & F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))                                                                        & 0\leq x,y\leq1       \\
                                      & f_1(x,y)=x                                                                                   &                      \\
                                      & f_2(x,y)=(1+10y)\Bigl(1-\Bigl(\frac{x}{1+10y}\Bigr)^2- \frac{x}{1+10y}\sin(2p\pi x)\Bigr)    &                      \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

First table with `$` and default `\arraystretch`.

[image]

Second table using `\newcolumntype` with `displaystyle` and `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray` with columns in display math and in-line math mode the table code is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec ={@{} l X[l, mode=dmath] Q[c,mode=math] @{}},
             row{1} = {mode=text},
             rowsep = 3pt
             }
    \toprule
MOP & Definition
        & Constraints                   \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=3]{l}   Schaffer Problem
    &   F=(f_1(x),f_2(x)) 
        &   -10^5\leq x\leq 10^5        \\
    &   f_1(x)=x^2
        &                               \\
    & f_2(x)=(x-2)^2
        &                               \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=4]{l}   Viennet (3)
    & F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y))                                                               
        & -4\leq x,y\leq4               \\
    & f_1(x,y)=0.5(x^2+y^2)+\sin(x^2+y^2)                                                          
        &                               \\
    & f_2(x,y)=\frac{(3x-2y+4)^2}{8}+\frac{(x-y+1)^2}{27}+15                                      
        &                               \\
    &   f_3(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}-1.1 e^{-x^2-y^2}                                                
        &                               \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=3]{l}   Kursawe problem
    &   F=(f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}))
        & -5\leq x_i\leq5               \\
    & f_1(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(-10 \exp\left(-0.2\sqrt{x_i^2+y_{i+1}^2}\right)\right)
        & i=1,2,3                       \\
    & f_2(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(|{x_i}|^{0.8}+5 \sin(x_i^3)\right)
        &                               \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=3]{c}   Dep problem
    &   F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))
        & 0\leq x,y\leq1                \\
    & f_1(x,y)=x
        &                               \\
    & f_2(x,y)=(1+10y)\Bigl(1-\Bigl(\frac{x}{1+10y}\Bigr)^2- \frac{x}{1+10y}\sin(2p\pi x)\Bigr)
        &                               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, a much cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `\multirow` for this, but I prefer not to.

I solve the problem by stating the equations and the constraints in a single top aligned `array`; the rows are separated by `\addlinespace` to add some air (changing `\arraystretch` would not work as well).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addvertspaces}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ \addlinespace }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% a local command to ease input
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{$\begin{array}[t]{@{}>{\displaystyle}l@{}}\addvertspaces{#1}\end{array}$}
\newcommand{\constr}[1]{$\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}\addvertspaces{#1}\end{array}$}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  >{\color{blue!70!black}}l
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
MOP & Definition & Constraints\\
\midrule
Schaffer Problem & 
\prob{
  F=(f_1(x),f_2(x)) \\
  f_1(x)=x^2, \\
  f_2(x)=(x-2)^2
} &
\constr{-10^5\leq x\leq 10^5} \\
\midrule
Viennet (3) &
\prob{
  F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y)) \\
  f_1(x,y)=0.5(x^2+y^2)+\sin(x^2+y^2), \\
  f_2(x,y)=\frac{(3x-2y+4)^2}{8}+\frac{(x-y+1)^2}{27}+15, \\
  f_3(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}-1.1 e^{-x^2-y^2}
} &
\constr{-4\leq x,y\leq4} \\
\midrule
Kursawe problem &
\prob{
  F=(f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x})) \\
  f_1(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\bigl(-10 \exp(-0.2\sqrt{\smash[b]{x_i^2+y_{i+1}^2}}\,)\bigr), \\
  f_2(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n \bigl(\abs{x_i}^{0.8}+5 \sin(x_i^3)\bigr)
} &
\constr{i=1,2,3 \\ -5\leq x_i\leq5} \\
\midrule
Dep problem &
\prob{
  F=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)) \\
  f_1(x,y)=x, \\
  f_2(x,y)=(1+10y)\Bigl(1-\Bigl(\frac{x}{1+10y}\Bigr)^2 
           -\frac{x}{1+10y}\sin(2p\pi x)\Bigr)
} &
\constr{0\leq x,y\leq1} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Unconstrained Functions}
\label{unconstrained}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\mid` is not a delimiter. Also the sine function should always be `\sin`. I used a trick in order to reduce the size of the square root.